# Custom User Profile Fields

Tags: custom-field, database, users

I have add new columns on wp_users and in /wp-admin/user.edit.php I add new fields and connect this to database, so if I put data on the database manually, the new fields recive that, but if I update or insert data on WordPress site in the new fields it don't update on the database and stay with same data I have put on the database manually.
What's wrong with this?
Thank you.

Comment: First of all, never make any changes in WP core files, it will get flush off after WP updates to new version. Instead you can add custom user profile fields using [hooks](https://www.templatemonster.com/blog/add-custom-user-meta-data-wordpress/) or [plugin](https://profilepress.net/custom-fields-wordpress-user-profile/).

Comment: I already tried plugins and they do not save the information in the database and what I need is that I store in the database the various information corresponding to the various columns that I created in the database because I need to tinker with the data using mirthconnect.
There is a plugin that stores the information in the database but it stores several information in a single column.

Comment: As Jiten said modifying Wordpress core files or core Wordpress tables is a really bad idea. Take a look at the [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin it makes things like adding custom fields to wp_users a lot easier, and doesn't break anything in the Wordpress core.

Comment: I already tried to use the plugin you indicated but it does not create the fields in the wp_users table, supposedly saves the data idependently.

Comment: If you use plugin, it saves custom field value in wp_usermeta table in key value format. If you add city field, you can get value using get_user_meta($userid, 'city', true);

Comment: @JitenGaikwad Repost:
I already tried plugins and they do not save the information in the database and what I need is that I store in the database the various information corresponding to the various columns that I created in the database because I need to tinker with the data using mirthconnect. There is a plugin that stores the information in the database but it stores several information in a single column.

Comment: @JoãoVaranda: It is not recommend to make any changes in the core files or in the database (Like add extra column in WP tables), as it will wipe out everything in next update.
Recommended way is to use custom fields and save the data as metadat. So for users extra information gets stored in wp_usermeta table, for posts it gets stored in wp_postmeta in meta_key and meta_value format, where meta_key is the field-name while meta_value is the corresponding values stored for that key with respect to post_id or user_id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to definitely want to do this with a plugin. Modifying WordPress Core files is an extremely bad idea as others have pointed out because every update will wipe them out and future versions may change the location/function of what you're editing. You can get away by adding it to the theme's `functions.php` file as well but you run into the same problem as with WP Core, updates will wipe them out. Writing a Plugin is your best option.

Say you wanted to add a field for a user to define their favorite color. You first would do the following:

```
function my_extra_author_fields( $user ) { ?>
    <h3>My Extra Author Fields</h3>

    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="favorite_color">Favorite Color</label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="favorite_color" id="favorite_color" class="regular-text" value="<?php esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'favorite_color', $user->ID ) ); ?>" />
                <br />
                <span class="description">Please enter your favorite color</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php }

add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'my_extra_author_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'my_extra_author_fields' );
```

This will create the new fields in the form for user profile but will not actually save anything yet. That part comes next:

```
function save_my_extra_author_fields( $user_id ) {

    // Check to see if user can edit this profile
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
        return false;

    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'favorite_color', $_POST['favorite_color'] );
}

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_my_extra_author_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_my_extra_author_fields' );
```

You will need to do a new `<tr>` element and `update_user_meta()` call for *each* custom field you want to add.

You can then access the value of these fields with `get_the_author_meta( 'favorite_color' )` if you want to use the return programmatically such as testing to see if the favorite color is set or use `the_author_meta( 'favorite_color' )` to simply echo it.

Comment: Where do I add the code you told me?

Comment: In a fresh plugin file in `/wp-content/plugins/{pluginname}`

Comment: I have no idea how to do it, supposedly just paste the two functions you gave me, add my fields and save a file in php and put it in the root folder of plugins right?
The problem is that I did this and the plugin does not appear on the site.

Comment: You create a new `.php` file in a folder under `/wp-content/plugins/`. At the top of the file place the comment block, one very similar to what you put in `style.css` for a theme, and then paste in those functions.